# 'NoneType' object is not iterable loop to get folder in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

i try loop for get file in present like `ap-sounteast/2021/02/12`, i got all region and put year, month, day but not work

then i try `2021/` and not working same reason

what's wrong with my code ?

```
year = now.strftime("%Y")
month = now.strftime("%m")
day = now.strftime("%d")

account = bucket.meta.client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket.name, Prefix='AWSLogs/', Delimiter='/')
for account in account.get('CommonPrefixes'):
    list_account = account.get('Prefix')

    region = bucket.meta.client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket.name, Prefix=(list_account+'CloudTrail/'), Delimiter='/')
    for region in region.get('CommonPrefixes'):
      region = region.get('Prefix')

      files = bucket.meta.client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket.name, Prefix=(region+year+'/'+month+'/'+day+'/'), Delimiter='/')
      for files in files.get('CommonPrefixes'):
        files = files.get('Prefix')
        print (files)
```

error

```
      9       files = bucket.meta.client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket.name, Prefix=(region+year+'/'+month+'/'+day+'/'), Delimiter='/')
---> 10       for files in files.get('CommonPrefixes'):
     11         files = files.get('Prefix')
     12         print (files)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the **full text** of the error and traceback. Also, please ensure your code is a self-contained [mre].

Answer (score 0):

When you want to run a for loop, you need to run it over 'iterable' object such as list and array. You tried to do `for files in files.get('CommonPrefixes'):` which is looping over the CommonPrefixes file. It seems like the file is nonetype.

If you do `print(type(files.get('CommonPrefixes'))` you can check what type it is.

You need to replace files.get('CommonPrefixes'). If you are sure this is the file you want, try to convert it to an array or list.

Answer (score 0):

i try different way, it's work

```
        region = (region.get('Prefix')+year+'/'+month+'/'+day+'/')
        
        files = list(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=region))
        for i in range(0, len(files)):
          getfile = (files[i].key)
```